# Overriding primary key column in Rails 4 and SQLite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, rails-migrations

After googling I'm still unable to find a successful way to override the primary key added by Rails when working with SQLite. So far I have the following basic migration:

```
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :requests, id: false do |t|
            t.string :id
            t.string :name
        end    
    end
end
```

The code above tells Rails to not add the default `id` primary key. Instead, I want to use an `id` of type string.

The problem arises with the limitations of SQLite's `ALTER` command, which cannot add a primary key after creating the table. Thus, I tried this workaround:

```
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :requests, id: false do |t|
            t.string :id
            t.string :name
        end    

        adapter_type = connection.adapter_name.downcase.to_sym    
        case adapter_type
            when :postgresql
                # TODO
            when :sqlite        
                execute <<-SQL          
                    DROP TABLE requests;
                    CREATE TABLE requests (id TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
                SQL
            else
                raise NotImplementedError, "Unknown adapter type '#{adapter_type}'"
            end

    end
end
```

After running `rake db:migrate` I get this output:

```
== 20140722082104 CreateRequests: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:requests, {:id=>false})
   -> 0.0010s
-- execute("          DROP TABLE requests;\n          CREATE TABLE requests (id
     TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);\n")
   -> 0.0010s
== 20140722082104 CreateRequests: migrated (0.0030s) ==========================
```

So, it seems everything went OK, but when I inspect the database file with a SQLite management program, table `requests` does not exist.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found the solution for myself: execute each SQL statement independently:

```
execute "DROP TABLE requests;"
execute "CREATE TABLE requests (id TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);"
```

**EDIT**

A more elegant solution to prevent creating the table by hand, specially when the table has many columns and we want to keep it synced with the call to ActiveRecord's `create_table` method:

```
#Get from SQLite's master table the SQL statement that creates the table, 
#and that was initially generated by Rails
sql = select_value("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='requests'")

#Only replace the definition of the 'id' column by adding the PRIMARY KEY
#constraint
sql.gsub!(/"id" [^,]+/, '"id" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY')     

#Delete the original table            
drop_table :requests 

#Create the table again
execute sql
```